# Getting an error on creating a CartVM to show in the header section of website

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on project for ecommerce where I have created function to add and display products. Now I wrote a function to Add product to cart with help of a partial view of Cart. However it is giving me an error on loading the page.

I created a CartVM like this:

```
public class CartVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrdName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get {return Quantity * Price; } }
}
```

Controller action for Cartpartial:

```
public IActionResult Cartpartial()
{
    // Init CartVM
    CartVM model = new CartVM();

    // Init Quantity
    int qty = 0;

    // Init Price
    decimal price = 0;

    // Check for cart Session
    var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetString("cart");

    if (cart != null)
    {
        // Get total qty and price
        List<CartVM> dataCart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartVM>>(cart);

        foreach(var item in dataCart)
        {
            qty += item.Quantity;
            price += item.Price;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Or set qty and price to 0
        model.Quantity = 0;
        model.Price = 0m;
    }

    // Return partial view with model
    return PartialView();
}
```

Cartpartial view

```
@model BuySell.Models.Cart.CartVM

<div class="ajaxcart">
    Your cart: @Model.Quantity
</div>
```

Calling partial view in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Home/Cartpartial.cshtml")
```

This is the error:

[image: Error image on loading partialview]

Page will load if I remove @Model.Quantity from the Cartpartial page, which wont be right approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the Cartpartial.cshtml partial view, we can know that, when use this partial view, it requires a CartVM instance, so when using `@await Html.PartialAsync()` method to render the partial view, we have to provide a CartVM. Otherwise, it will show the NullReference exception.

You can refer to the following sample:
In the Index action, we create the CartVM and use TempData to store it.

```
 public IActionResult Index()
            {
                CartVM model = new CartVM();
                model.PrdName = "ProductA";

                TempData["model"] = model;
                return View();
            }
```

Then in the _Layout.cshtml, if the TempData is not null, we can get the CartVM from TempData and transfer to the partial view, use the following code.

```
 @if (TempData["model"] !=null)
                {
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Home/Cartpartial.cshtml", (CartVM)TempData["model"])
                }
```

In this scenario, when access the Index page, it will show the cart partial view without any exception.

Note: In the above sample, Data initialization is in Index method, so we have to navigate to the Index page. And, I'm using TempData. You can also use ViewData, ViewBag or Session.

Besides, please check your Cartpartial action method, you forget return the model to the view page, change the code as below:

```
public IActionResult Cartpartial()
{
    // Init CartVM
    CartVM model = new CartVM();
    // Init Quantity
    int qty = 0;
    ...
    // Return partial view with model
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so very much for your resposne. Tried the above code but getting error as InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType6`1[System.String]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'BuySell.Models.Cart.CartVM'.

Comment: @Rezo, could you make sure you have added the ` return PartialView(model);`  modify the `_Layout.cshtml` to `@await Html.PartialAsync("Cartpartial")`

Comment: Very much the same error : spNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Home_Cartpartial.ExecuteAsync() in Cartpartial.cshtml
+
    Your cart: @Model.Quantity

Comment: I tested with a View and View works and shows the right value.

Comment: Somehow the PartialView is messing it all

Comment: @Rezo please check modified answer

Comment: this seems to be a workaround and not solution. Problem statement still remains open, will see what can be done. But, appreciate your help. THank you

Comment: @Rezo in the Cartpartial page could you try adding the if-else statement top check the model is null or not. if it is not null try to display Quantity